# Editing Mac OS X login items in Objective-C through AppleScript

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, authentication, applescript

In my Cocoa program, I want to examine what programs are registered to run at startup and modify that list as I feel appropriate.  In order to be compatible with Tiger it seems like I need to work through AppleScript.  I currently have the following code:

```
NSDictionary* errorDict;
NSAppleEventDescriptor* returnDescriptor = NULL;

NSString *appleSource = @"tell application \"System Events\"\n\
get every login item\n\
end tell";
NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: appleSource];

returnDescriptor = [appleScript executeAndReturnError: &errorDict];
```

If I run that command in AppleScript, I get back an array of login items.  However, I can't figure out how to iterate through this array in Objective-C.  More specifically, I want to examine the names and paths of the programs registered to run at startup.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** I figured this out.  Here is some sample code.  The key is using AEKeyword's, which are very poorly documented.  The best reference is here: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/AppleScript/ASTerminology_AppleEventCodes/TermsAndCodes.html

```
const AEKeyword aeName = 'pnam';
const AEKeyword aePath = 'ppth';

...

NSDictionary* errorDict;
NSAppleEventDescriptor* getLoginItemsRD = NULL;
NSString *getLoginItemsSrc = @"tell application \"System Events\"\n\
                               get properties of every login item\n\
                               end tell";
NSAppleScript *getLoginItemsScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: getLoginItemsSrc];
getLoginItemsRD = [getLoginItemsScript executeAndReturnError: &errorDict];
[getLoginItemsScript release];

int i;
int numLoginItems = [getLoginItemsRD numberOfItems];
for (i = 1; i <= numLoginItems; i++)
{
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *loginItem = [getLoginItemsRD descriptorAtIndex:i];
    NSString *loginItemName = [[loginItem descriptorForKeyword:aeName] stringValue];
    NSString *loginItemPath = [[loginItem descriptorForKeyword:aePath] stringValue];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apple has some source code which can manage login items for Tiger and earlier. I believe you're supposed to get it from ADC but I found it floating around here:

[LoginItemAPI.h](http://uncwddas.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/other/boinc/mac_installer/LoginItemAPI.h)

[LoginItemAPI.c](http://uncwddas.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/other/boinc/mac_installer/LoginItemAPI.c)