# How do I get a get a mac os x app I created to load on startup programmatically?

Tags: macos, plist, dmg

I have this jar file that I turned into a dmg.  Now, what I would like to have happen is that when a user runs this dmg and installs the application, that this application will always load on startup.

Is this an easy task to complete? Can I do it by modifying the plist file that comes with the package contents or is it much more difficult than that?

Comment: To do this during installation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947925/add-app-to-osx-login-items-during-a-package-maker-installer-postflight-script

Comment: Does "startup" mean boot or login?  Is it supposed to run if a different user than the one who installed the dmg logs in?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [launchctl](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/launchctl.1.html) for your needs. You can place a .launchd.conf in your user's HOME directory, from the looks of things, that will run automatically at startup.