# OSX 10.8 LoginItems

Tags: macos, startup, login-script

I found this [Add app to OSX "Login Items" during a Package Maker installer postflight script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947925/add-app-to-osx-login-items-during-a-package-maker-installer-postflight-script/7643260#7643260) but it doesn't appear to work in OSX 10.8?

This is from the other question and works in everything else...

```
defaults write \
    /Library/Preferences/loginwindow \
    AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary \
    -array-add '{ "Path" = "/path/to/script"; "Hide" = "0"; }'
```

How can I add my app to loginItems in OSX Mountain Lion (10.8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X 10.8 is under [NDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement), we are not at liberty of giving details about it but i can tell you that there is no /Library/Preferences/loginwindow under 10.7 or any other recent OSX version, you should be doing :

```
defaults write \
    ~/Library/Preferences/loginwindow \
    AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary \
    -array-add '{ "Path" = "/path/to/script"; "Hide" = "0"; }'
```

Notice the "~" tilde was missing

Comment: Note that this only adds it to the current user's login items, not the *global* login items. Adding to those only seems to be possible via the Launch Services' Shared File List API now.

Comment: Since this isn't an answer, but an admonition about NDA, it should be a comment. Consider updating this with a **real answer** now that 10.8 has been out for a while.

Answer (score -1):

OS X 10.8 stores login items in com.apple.loginwindow.plist

Comment: Citation? As far as I can tell, this is in fact false. Global login items are now stored in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist` - but you should not modify this file directly. Instead, use the Launch Services' Shared File List API (in `LSSharedFileList.h`). (10.6 and up)