# Execute intercative process at osx startup

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to make my mac execute safari every time user admin is logged in.
currently I tried to use LaunchDeamons to execute open -a safari and I get:

error -610 noUserInteractionAllowed: no user interaction allowed.

How can I execute process as interactive at logging?

I have tried this also:

https://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/osx/set-automatic-startup-and-login-items-in-mac-os-x/

Didn't work.

The solution I am seeking is simply executing some python script in user terminal in login, I am new to mac (coming from windows) but I thought this will be trivial, just adding my script to some folder..

Comment: Have you had a look at the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947925/ ?

Comment: I have tried loginitems and to my understanding LaunchDeamons is the same as LaunchAgents just for root. I didn't try to  compile Obj-c code to a binary and the user stated he doesn't know if it will work.

Comment: Actually when I add safari to loginitems it doesn't work! (safari wont open) even though apple docs clearly state that it should work.